# Connecting to a database via excel vba

Tags: excel

I have created this utility in Excel (and connect to a MS Access) The database -in Microsoft Access, is completed. I am in the second Phase of the project; I have successfully published database to SharePoint (lists) and will access it via Excel/Access. The database contains Linked Lists. The database open, but crashes when reading tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Indeed. The front end interface is via Microsoft excel. Using ADODB I connect to a Microsoft Database. This is the code that connects to Access.

Comment: Set mCnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With mCnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\SomeFolder\dbdata.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
        .Open
Now, here comes the tricky part: the Access database, contains linked tables to SharePoint Lists. I need to access these linked tables; using recordsets but it crashes the moment it opens the recordset

Comment: Set mCmd = New ADODB.Command 
mCmd.ActiveConnection = mCnn
mCmd.CommandText = mSQL
Set mRS = New ADODB.Recordset 
mRS.CursorLocation = adUseServer
mRS.Open source:=mCmd, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic

The moment the code hits the .Open it crashes -or should I say it never comes back. It spins and spins. I have not been able to resolve the issue as of today. Any help would be greatly appreciated!